# C++ Windows XP: Не является приложением Win32

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

У меня известная проблема - я строю exe файл в MS Visual Studio 2015 Windows 8.1, запускаю на Windows XP Professional 2002 SP3. Выскакивает ошибка - MyBuild.exe Не является приложением Win32.

Сразу оговорюсь, что все похожие темы прочитал, применил все рекомендации в плане настроек проекта и обновлений. Ничего не помогло (

Comment: Может, он и на самом деле не является приложением Win32? Что именно и как именно «строите»-то? 32 или 64 бита?

Comment: Нет, строю именно 32 бита. Это готовый проект, без вариантов.

Answer (score 1):

В Visual Studio есть специальный тулкит для компиляции под WinXP, его и нужно использовать для сборки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я уже так сделал, не помогло.

Comment: Вы какие-то библиотеки подключаете к проекту? Все они тоже должны быть собраны данным тулкитом. Попробуйте написать обычный HelloWorld и попробуйте запустить на XP.

Comment: Да, подключаю. Надо попробовать.

Comment: Да, все lib-ы собраны, как написано, но все равно та же ошибка.

Comment: А HelloWorld пробовали собрать и запустить на XP?